# .NET Remoting: Getting underlying socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, remoting

I'm writing a light remoting app to assist in debugging a problem with remoting communication. This app mimics much of what a larger application does:

> Periodically sends a heartbeat to
>   another peer application, and
>   periodically verifies that a heartbeat
>   has been received within some time
>   threshold.

What we're seeing is in our big application, the heartbeats seem to get dropped. One peer will go for long periods of time without seeing heartbeats from another peer, until the peer that is "dead" is restarted. The big application is responsive in all other ways. We believe it has something to do with the network setup. We were able to repro the problem locally, and fixed it by making some configuration changes to our test environment.

To help our customer diagnose the issue, the mini-remoting app needs to log as much information as possible.

So, is there a way to get the underlying socket for the remoting connection? I'm aware that I could write a custom sink for this, but I'd like to keep the actual remoting process as close to what is implemented in the big app as possible.

Also as an aside, any ideas why the big-app might be "dropping" heartbeats?

Comment: Are you sure that the peer whose heartbeats are "dropped" is actually sending the heartbeats?

Comment: Actually, as in have verified the data makes it to the wire--no. According to the code itself, it claims to have sent the heartbeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the direct answer but as a way to get to it. can you use reflection to look into the sockets class, or get the class from a symbol server. If that still doesn't help, you could always copy/paste the class into you're own namespace so you can expose whatever internals you need to expose... Just a thought.